# Using ValidationError and not redirecting to a new page

Tags: django, django-forms

My form looks like this:

```
class Form(forms.Form):                                                                                                                                                               
    smth = forms.ChoiceField(label='Smth', choices=[(x, x) for x in my_settings.measurements])                                                                                                                                         

    def clean_smth(self):                                                                                                                                                                   
        smth = self.cleaned_data['smth']
        problem_condition = some_convoluted_process(smth)                                                                                                                                                   
        if problem_condition:                                                                                                                                                                             
            raise ValidationError("this sucks")                                                                                                                                                   
        return smth
```

My view has this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                             
    try:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        form = Form(request.POST)                                                                                                                                         
    except ValidationError as e:                                                                                                                                                       
        pass                                                                                                                                                                             
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                
        if form.is_valid():                                                                                                                                                      
            form.save()                                                                                                                                                          
            return redirect('this_current_page')                                                                                                                                                  

else:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    form = Form()
```

I'm using custom validation for the form.

In an ideal world, the user would submit the form and be redirected to the same exact page.  If there were an error, the user would be on the same page but the error would be listed below the form.  Instead, the error (inserted by the exception `ValidationError`) ends up in the middle of the form, creating an ugly line break.  I've tried many ways to format / handle `ValidationError` in the template, to no avail.

I want to do this all on the same page; not have some annoying separate page that the user is redirected to in case of error.  It's easier to just correct the form *in situ* than to see the fault on another page, press back, and try again.

How can I have the error printed prettily on the same template, when the error comes from raising the exception?  I am using `raise ValidationError` because the examples I find online about custom form validation say to use an exception when things go awry with that validation.

Comment: you can use `form.errors` in templates, it catches all the validation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                             
    if form.is_valid():                                                                                                                                                      
        form.save()                                                                                                                                                          
        return redirect('this_current_page')   
    else:
        print('Error: form invalid')
        # you can alert the user here  with django message framework for example                                                                                                                                            

else:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    form = Form()
```

forms.py

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):  
         cleaned_data = super(YourForm,self).clean()                                                                                                                                                                 
         smth = cleaned_data.get('smth')                                                                                                                                            
         if some_convoluted_process(smth): # Depending of what your function does                                                                                                                                                                              
             self.add_error("smth","this sucks")                                                                                                                                                   
         return cleaned_data
```

With the following, you are free to handle the `form` the way you want rather than: `{{form}}` , `{{form.as_p}}`, `{{form.as_table}}`

```
 <div id="trigger_form" class="container">                                                                                                                    
     <h4>Create Alert Trigger</h4> 
     <form action="/triggers/{{ stationid }}/" class="form" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}    
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label class="control-label" for="{{form.meas_type.id_for_label}}">Meas Type *</label>

                  {% if form.meas_type.errors %}
                      <label class="color-red">
                          {{form.meas_type.errors.as_text}}</i>
                      </label>
                  {% endif %}
                  {{ form.meas_type }} 
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label class="control-label" for="{{form.trig_type.id_for_label}}">Trig Type *</label>

                  {% if form.trig_type.errors %}
                      <label class="color-red">
                          {{form.trig_type.errors.as_text}}</i>
                      </label>
                  {% endif %}
                  {{ form.trig_type }} 
              </div>
          </div>
     </form> 
 </div>
```

Comment: you still have access to it for each field, `form.field_name.errors`

Comment: ok, edit your question with a part of the template... let me see so I can help you

Comment: based on your code, you would access errors for the field `smth`, with `form.smth.errors`

Comment: So you want to handle with, in `forms.py` as well?

Comment: The custom validation is done in forms.py (see my first code snipped above)

Comment: see how you can deal with `forms.py` with my updated answer to attaching error to a specific field... ok!
what do you wanna do now?

Comment: That works - thank you.  But it's back to the same problem: I can print my errors after the form, on the same page, but still right after the field that has the error ("smth" in this case), there is a line break and the error printed there.  So I have: [field] [field] [errormsg] [smth] [field] [my printed errors].  It's the same as raising the exception - I have my error but it still prints it (magically) in the middle of the form and jacks up the appearance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170572/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-horse-hair).